# Two commands in one process in shell in android

Tags: android

I want to set two commands in one process on android.
I know that `nativeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` but I want to add whoami in the same process. This is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
public static   void go()

{

    String[] command = {"/system/bin/sh", "-c", "ps | grep apps ; ls"};
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    try {
        Process process =processBuilder.start();



     InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",
                Arrays.toString(command));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
                Log.e("output of go-->", "==>"+line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the context of the question.  Android is a linux-kernel based system, but with a very atypical userspace - many of your assumptions (such as the existence of a `bash`) will need to be corrected.

Comment: in case of android change the below statements:String[] command = {"/system/bin/sh", "-c", "ps | grep apps ; ls"};
     ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

Comment: i just executed sample commands and it is working fine (like ps and ls). you can verify your commands

Answer (score 0):

`su -c "command"` will run your command as superuser (something like `sudo` in Debian based systems)

Comment: This actually depends on the specific hacked `su` being used - some support that, others do not making it necessary to pipe commands into the stdin of the resulting shell.  And there is no ultimate standard, because the standard (unhacked) android `su` is not usable by application code to begin with.

Comment: I checked it on my tablet and it worked, I didn't know, that it may not, thanks for clarification.